How do show just the conditionally formatted colour scales in a bar chart?
I am trying to create a heat map of pipeline survey data as a bar chart just showing the transient colours.
I have a list of position and current density values which I have conditionally formatted as a colour scale.
How do I replicate this as a chart (ignoring the actual data values but just showing the colours as a block)?

I tried many Excel functions. I can only display the heat map as a spreadsheet rather than a bar chart. The data can cover 1000s of rows so I'm looking to display this as a chart, as one visual representation showing the density.

Run a loop over each of the cells with the conditional format and execute c.interior.color = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color  Now you can copy/pastespecial+transpose and remove the values from the colored cells while keeping the colors.

Note: The color of the bars in the chart does not automatically update when the data source changes.
Microsoft documentation:

Series.XValues property (Excel)


Range.Insert method (Excel)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub HeadMapColumnChart()
    Dim srcRng As Range, i As Long, oSerCol As Series
    Set srcRng = Range("C1").CurrentRegion
    Columns("C").Insert
    With srcRng.Columns("C")
        .Value = "1"
        .Cells(1).Value = "CD"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData Source:=srcRng.Columns("C")
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone)
        .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
        Set oSerCol = .FullSeriesCollection(1)
    End With
    With srcRng.Columns(1)
        oSerCol.XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Address
    End With
    For i = 2 To srcRng.Rows.Count
        oSerCol.Points(i - 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Cells(i, "B").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next
End Sub



You can use property .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color to read the real color of a cell given by conditional formatting. Using it I would make a bar chart with all columns with value 1 and then use VBA code to format each bar of the chart.
Sub ColorChart()
Dim loData As ListObject
Dim myRng As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set loData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblChartData")

For i = 1 To loData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    Set myRng = loData.ListColumns("CD").DataBodyRange(i)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
    Selection.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = myRng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

Next i

End Sub

I based it on a table as it gives me more confidence that the chart has the same range as the values which we read to get colors.
It looks like this:
Bar chart formatted with the same colors as table
